# How to cast a model of T type to 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' in C#?

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to add some parameters in the class *Job.cs*

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public int JobPropertyType { get; set; }
        public string JobValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using Dapper for Inserting Data in the tables.
*Repository.cs*

```
public async Task<T> Add(T entity)
        {
            using (var connection = await _connectionFactory.GetConnectionAsync())
            {
                return await connection.InsertAsync<T>(entity);
            }
        }
```

I have used DapperMapper for mapping table and data.
*Mapper.cs*

```
public class JobMapper: ClassMapper<Job>
    {
        public JobMapper()
        {
            Schema("Job");
            Table("Job");
            Map(m => m.JobId).Column("JobId");
            Map(m => m.JobPropertyType).Column("JobPropertyType");
            Map(m => m.JobValue).Column("JobValue");
        }
    }
```

Here is the *JobService.cs*

```
public async Task<Job> InsertJob(int jobId, int jobPropertyType, string jobValue)
        {
            var job = new Job
            {
                JobId = jobId,
                JobPropertyType = jobPropertyType,
                JobValue = jobValue
            };

            return await this.Repository.Add(job);
        }
```

Another service sending data

```
public async Task AddJob(int jobId, string snapshot)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(snapshot))
            {
               await  _jobService.InsertJob(jobId, (int)JobPropertiesEnum.Snapshot, snapshot);
            }
```

When I am trying to Insert data here, I am getting this exception:

**Message=Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'Test.Job'.** at the time of Inserting (InsertyAsync() in the Repository)

**How can I cast it into Dynamic.ExpandoObject?**

Comment: You can't "cast" it - an `ExpandoObject` is not a `Job`. But it's not clear where you're getting an `ExpandoObject` to know what to change.

Comment: I am getting exception at the InsertAsync and I have added more details in the question for clarity. @DStanley

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? The `ExpandoObject` must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: It says: Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Dapper-Extensions from here: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/tree/master/DapperExtensions

InsertAsync returns a Task<dynamic>, dynamic is an ExpandoObject, so your problem arises when you try to get the return value. The return value is the key of the inserted entity.

You can change your code to something like this (I didn't have time to test it):

```cs
public async Task<T> Add(T entity)
{
    using (var connection = await _connectionFactory.GetConnectionAsync())
    {
        var result = await connection.InsertAsync<T>(entity);
        entity.Id = (int) result;
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will show error on entity.Id. Since T type entity does not have id. @Palle Due

Comment: Error Message: T does not contain a definition for Id.

Comment: for the last line, Error message: Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'T' rather than Task<T>

Comment: OK, I've changed the last line, to return just the entity.  How you will go about setting Id on the entity, when you don't have an interface or a base class, I don't know. Maybe you should just return the id. The short of the long is that InsertAsync won't return an entity, just the Id of it.